# Remove special characters from a string except whitespace

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I am looking for a regular expression to remove all special characters from a string, except whitespace. And maybe replace all multi- whitespaces with a single whitespace.

For example `"[one@ !two    three-four]"` should become `"one two three-four"`

I tried using  `str = Regex.Replace(strTemp, "^[-_,A-Za-z0-9]$", "").Trim()` but it does not work. I also tried few more but they either get rid of the whitespace or do not replace all the special characters.

Comment: What about `one#two` -- would that be replaced with `one two` or `onetwo`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ]+
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/69

Comment: Thanks! It does not take care of extra spaces but works fine otherwise

Comment: @ElenaDBA try now.took care of multiple spcaes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `[^\w\s]` to remove all special characters other than words and white spaces, then replace:

```
Regex.Replace("[one@ !two three-four]", "[^\w\s]", "").Replace("  ", " ").Trim
```

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD:**

instead of trying to use replace use replaceAll eg :

```
String InputString= "[one@ !two    three-four]";

String testOutput = InputString.replaceAll("[\\[\\-!,*)@#%(&$_?.^\\]]", "").replaceAll("( )+", " ");

Log.d("THE OUTPUT", testOutput);
```

This will give an output of *one two three-four*.

**EXPLANATION:**

`.replaceAll("[\\[\\-!,*)@#%(&$_?.^\\]]", "")` this replaces ALL the special characters present between the first and last brackets[]

`.replaceAll("( )+", " ")` this replaces more than 1 whitespace with just 1 whitespace

**REPLACING THE - symbol:**

just add the symbol to the regex like this `.replaceAll("[\\[\\-!,*)@#%(&$_?.^\\]]", "")`

*Hope this helps :)*